# php-mysql update without deleting data already there

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update a Comment Blob in a mysql database without deleting data already in it.

```
$SQLstring="INSERT INTO Participant(Role,Comment)
            VALUES('$Costume','$Comment')
            WHERE Fname='$FirstName' AND Lname='$LastName'";
```

This doesn't want to work if there is  already data in the "Comment" field and if  I use UPDATE it will replace the data.

I want to keep data that is there and simple add to it

Comment: You still need to use UPDATE but you just need to append your values. Google it. It's not difficult to do.

Comment: Don't do that! Don't store multiple values in one column. Differ the data and make a record for every time you add something

Comment: This is a simple project for my local church. The comment blob is in the users table and it would be nice just to see all comments you make at one time. The is only going to be used around Christmas for participants and what items are loaned out to them. Stuff goes missing. I am new to all this i am just glad I am doing as good as I am.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to do it:

```
$Rolequery = mysql_query("UPDATE `Participant` SET Role=CONCAT(Role, ',$role') WHERE Fname='$FirstName' AND Lname='$LastName'");
$Commentquery = mysql_query("UPDATE `Participant` SET Comment=CONCAT(Comment, ',$Comment') WHERE Fname='$FirstName' AND Lname='$LastName'");
```